# PHP header() not sending custom message

Tags: php, rest, header

I would like my server to return a header with a custom message. Using the header() function, I can generate the appropriate headers but the message always reverts to some standard string, not the text I provide.

For example, if I put this in my server code

```
header ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 501 test error', true, 501);
```

I always see `501 Not Implemented` in my client. For clients, I've used Postman and also my Xamarin Forms client app. With the latter, I stopped it in the debugger to look at the text returned from `httpClient.GetAsynch()`.

I've also tried having only the first parameter

```
header ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 501 test error');
```

but I get the same results.

Here's another try. I returned this:

```
header ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' Status: 501 test error', true, 501);
```

But curl on a command line shows this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 24 Dec 2020 17:20:54 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46", h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000
```

And, if I take out "Status: ", I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 24 Dec 2020 17:28:09 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46", h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000
```

Comment: `Status:` is more likely to be retained than the faux [rfc2616_headers](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/97d2dd0f90b328e771b60634cc377fd20eececbc/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L307) syntax. Anyway, also depends on the protocol (mod_php, cgi, fpm) and webserver.

Comment: What do you mean ? Should I create a string like 'STATUS 501 test error' ?

Comment: Since it not an RFC compliant Header the client dont understand it

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Is there a solution ? If so, what should I do ? Please post an answer, if you have one.

Comment: A HTTP header must be in the specific format `name:value`, but you do not provide it properly

Comment: @LarsStegelitz - if I follow you, I should be including "Status:" in the header text. Please see my post again, I added a couple more tests towards the end. Still doesn't work.

Comment: As @mario basically said, depending on how your PHP is being routed something might be just stripping it out as non-standard. And also as mario said, that thing isn't technically a header, it is generally called the [status line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2). Because that needs to follow a very specific format, I wouldn't be surprised if PHP, a server or a client cleansed it automatically. [HTTP/2 speaks](https://martinthomson.github.io/http2v2/draft-thomson-httpbis-http2bis.html#name-pseudo-header-fields) to this, too.

Comment: Well, I think I'll just let this sit and use the standard error messages for now. It seems like implementations are inconsistent. W3.org states the codes are extensible, though I don't see anything about the messages being customizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reading, I believe the right way to provide a custom message for an error is to send it in the `body`, not the `header`.

So, for example, to provide a custom message "missing weight=x parameter, one can use this code:

```
http_response_coede (400);
print json_encode (array ('error' => 400, 
                          'message' => 'missing weight=x parameter');
```

Then, in your client, you parse this json string from the result body.

Answer (score 1):

`header("HTTP/1.1 …")` is a workaround for CGI setups. It's not a HTTP header as such. It's transformed and cleansed by PHP-FPM in most cases: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/97d2dd0f90b328e771b60634cc377fd20eececbc/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L307 if sent that way.

This is how you set a Status: header:

```
header("Status: 429 Begone!");
```

Now, if your webserver (LiteSpeed) strips out custom messages, then that's that. Nothing PHP can do about it. You'll have to find a server config workaround then. (e.g. `Header add` with some `if=` for Apache)

In short, give it a rest with `SERVER_PROTOCOL` unless your SAPI binding requires it. Upgrading PHP is an option if you run into troubles otherwise. Else you'll have to live with the standardized status message.

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen if you use HTTP/2, which no longer has the status text.